# Treating Git repository like regular project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, github

I have recently created a new repository on Github. I would like to edit and run/test it using Eclipse Juno. I have successfully imported it and followed all the directions for use with EGit but for some reason whenever I try to debug or run a file in the Git repo on Eclipse, it forces me to do an ‘Ant Build’ (and subsequently tells me no Ant Build file can be found). I found a solution online that involved changing the debugging preferences for the file/repository but when I open the preferences for files in my repo, I cannot find anything relating to debugging.

Does anyone know how to get Eclipse to treat a Git repo like a regular project in terms of debugging and running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your project is not being recognized as a Java project.  You will need to make changes to your `.project` file and add a `.classpath` file.

In your `.project` file, add this in the `buildSpec` section:

```xml
<buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

if there is not `buildSpec` section, then add this:

```xml
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
```

And create a simple `.classpath` file, something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Once you have that, you can make changes to it in `Project` -> `Java Build`.